# How to get the aliases of all data nodes in DolphinDB

Tags: database, dolphindb

I deploy a DolphinDB cluster the config is as bellow,

```
mode=controller
localSite=192.168.1.12:19100:master

localSite,mode
192.168.1.12:19110:agent_c1,agent
192.168.1.13:19110:agent_c2,agent
192.168.1.12:19111:DFS_NODE1,datanode
192.168.1.12:19112:DFS_NODE2,datanode
192.168.1.13:19111:DFS_NODE3,datanode
192.168.1.13:19112:DFS_NODE4,datanode
```

I connect 192.168.1.13:19111using dolphindb GUI, then execute the following code,

```
getNodeAlias()
```

Then get the alias of the local node,namely DFS_NODE3. Next, I want to get the aliases of  all the other data nodes. Is there an function such as getNodeAlias for getting the aliases of  all data nodes?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

1) On controller node, running function getClusterPerf() will return a table with all details. The "name" field in particular is what you are looking for.

2) On any data node, run pnodeRun(getNodeAlias), which basically runs getNodeAlias on each node and returns all results as a table.